# how to use ajax autocallback

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have one index page containing one input tag and one division, with one ajax function which gives me data from server.Problem:- 1)with single letter give me 3 record, after i add one more letter it work fine but when i delete on letter it give me another copy of that data means it print data 2times.please solve this.

```js
<!-- My Ajax Function -->

function sendInfo() {
    var compName = $('#compName').val();

    if(compName != null) {    
        $.get(
            'RoomReservationServlet?action=RoomReservation&processName=customerDetailJson',
            {c_CompName : compName}, 
            function(responseJson) {                 
                if (responseJson != null) {  
                    $('#spn_hint').fadeIn();
                    $.each( responseJson, function(key, value) {
                        $('#spn_hint').append('<li value=' + value['Com_Name'] + '>'+ value['Com_Name'] + '</li>');                                                        
                    });  
                } else {
                    alert("Jason : Empty");
                }
        });                              
    } else if(compName == null) {
        alert("exit");
        $('#spn_hint').fadeOut();
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- My html code -->

<label for="number">Company Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="compName" placeholder="Company Name" required style="overflow:scroll; " onkeyup="sendInfo();">
<div id="spn_hint" style="display:none;position:absolute;"></div>
```

Comment: `append` is the culprit. Use `replaceWith`.

Comment: it works but it gives me only single record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could clear the div before appending to it:

```
if (responseJson != null) {  
    $('#spn_hint').empty(); //Clears all child elements so that you can start fresh
    $('#spn_hint').fadeIn();
    $ .each( responseJson, function(key, value) {
         $('#spn_hint').append('<li value=' + value['Com_Name'] + '>'+ value['Com_Name']    + '</li>');                                                                     
    });  
}
```